# Xamarin.Forms iOS full screen image splash screen using storyboard

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, splash-screen, xcode-storyboard

In my Xamarin Forms Application, I used Storyboard as Splash screen,
In Splash screen I need to display a fullscreen image splash screen so what I do is I added a assets image and inside asset image, I added different image sizes 1x 2x 3x.

[image: Media.x assets]
and on my Storyboard, I have this setting

[image: Story board]
Knowing that I set different images from different sizes, I'm still having an issue when I run my app from a different device simulator. the splash screen with a fullscreen image becomes weird.
Please see below images for the results

[image: EMULATOR]
Anyone whats to share there sample solutions regarding this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Adding image in Assets add your converted images to your resources folder.

For Splash Screen image adjustment follow this link
https://tomsoderling.github.io/Use-all-the-space-on-iPhone-X/

Answer (score 0):

By your second image, I can tell your problem is with the constraints. As you can see the ImageView has red lines around. That means there are some issues with your constraints that you need to fix. What is happening is that iOS might be having issues when rendering your page and it's doing whatever is possible.

If you want to cover your whole screen (fullscreen) on the splashscreen with your image the constraints that work for me are:

```
ImageView -> Top Space Equal 0 to SuperView    
ImageView -> Leading Space Equal 0 to SuperView    
ImageView -> Equal Height 0 to SuperView    
ImageView -> Equal Width 0 to SuperView
```

The above will position the image at the left and top corner and then it will match the same width and height of your SuperView. That way no matter what the Superview size is the `ImageView` will update accordingly.

Something else to add is changing the `ImageView` `ContentMode` to **AspectFill**.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already try that approach, it works from iPhone X but in other devices like XR  XS Max was no success for full-screen image